# Dropdown menu without javascript

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu with tabs, and on hover of a tab a list of things appear at the bottom of the tab. Then, I wanted to do that the list of thing go down with a transition( before it was display:block). My problem is that when the transition will start, the top of the list must be a certain multiplication ( the width of a tab * the number of tabs ). But I don't want any javascript.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: post your code here if you want serious answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have it now. But maybe in two days.

Comment: please insert your Html and css code

Comment: use the answer of morteza tavakoli as exemple

Answer (score 13):

it is my sample of css dropdown menu: i hope be useful:

in HTML, and CSS:

```css
#menu, #menu ul
{
 list-style: none;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 background-color: #ecffec;
 padding: 0 0 26px 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#menu li
{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #ecffec;
 position: relative;
}
#menu ul
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 left: -1px;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0;
 display: none;
}
#menu ul li
{
 float: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 15px;
}
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited
{
 display: block;
 font-family: Tahoma;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 padding: 5px;
}
#menu li:hover
{
 background-color: #ffd98a;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu li:hover ul
{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Programming Language</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Asp Classic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ASP.NET</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">javascript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Perl</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Database</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">SQL Server 2005</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oracle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DB2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
   <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user1365010 what is missing from this?

Comment: @ScottBartell Simply, this is not the answer of my question but just an example to work on. See the comments of the question

Comment: also see example at http://www.ourtuts.com/create-a-drop-down-navigation-menu-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: @Morteza Thanks for your code its useful. However a get a transparent dropdown block, do you know how to make it an opaque one?

Comment: in "#menu li:hover ul" section add opacity: 0.5. opacity can change between 0 and 1. full transparent or opaque

Comment: This works great with a mouse but should include `:focus` as a backup for keyboard users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://codepen.io/markcaron/pen/wdVmpB?

**html part**

```
<h2>Checkbox version</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-dropdown" value="" name="my-checkbox">
  <label for="my-dropdown"
     data-toggle="dropdown">
  Choose one
  </label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/covfefe">Covfefe</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>


<h2>Anchor version</h2>

 <div class="dropdown">
  <ul id="my-dropdown2">
    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/covfefe">Covfefe</a></li>
 </ul>
  <a href="#my-dropdown2"
    aria-controls="my-dropdown2"
    role="button"
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    id="my-dropdown2-btn">
  Choose one
  </a>
     <a href="#my-dropdown2-btn"
     aria-controls="my-dropdown2"
    role="button"
     data-toggle="dropdown"
     class="close">
  Close dropdown
  </a>
 </div>
```

**css part**

better to see the link above!
check it out!