# How to create a drop-down list with white background on clicking a three dot image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a screenshot as shown below which I am trying to replicate in HTML, CSS and JS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate three dots image as shown in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Elharony/5a89bd3d/35/embedded/result/).

The **HTML code** belonging to three dots image is:

```
<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
    <form>
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <img src="https://s9.postimg.org/d6s4xvykv/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">
    </form>
</div>
```

The **CSS code** belonging to three dots image is:

```
.nav-top-searchbar {
    position: relative;
}

#ellipsis {
    top: 12px; // Sounds good and a bit centered [ Vertically ]
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
}

.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

On clicking the three dots image, it should create a list of drop-downs (View Status, Release Bills, Add Attendee, Export as..., View in Google Sheets, Send Notifications) as shown above in the screenshot. I am wondering what changes I need to make in HTML and CSS codes in order to get the drop-down.

Answer (score 2):

Without any javascript, you can do this. Note, `tabindex` is important here and positioning of elements. Otherwise just do it the javascript way and toggle a class `onclick`.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: none;
}
.toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.toggler:focus + .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div tabindex="1" class="toggler">...</div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    your elements here
  </div>
</div>
```

Your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/1/

```css
#ellipsis {
    top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}
#ellipsis:focus {
 outline: none;
}
#ellipsis:focus + .dropdown {
 display: block;
}


input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
}

.dropdown {
 background-color: lightblue;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 height: 150px;
 right: 0;
 width: 200px;
 z-index: 10;
}

.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
    <form>
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search">
    <div style="">
     <img tabindex="1" src="https://s9.postimg.org/d6s4xvykv/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">
     <div class="dropdown">
      insert your stuff here
     </div>     
    </div>
        

    </form>
</div>


<div class="body-manage-attendees">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                Number
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                Table
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Amanda Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Andy Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                No Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Cameron Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                No Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Dana Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                53
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Absent
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Eve Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Absent
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe's Guest1
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe's Guest 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                15
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                No Bill
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe's Guest 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                16
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Lydia Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Noah Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Meena Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Brenda Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Cameron Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Brenda Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Cameron Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Noah Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Dana Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                53
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Unpaid
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Eve Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Items Received
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Items Received
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe's Guest1
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Items Waiting
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Unpaid
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation.. can you tell me how to integrate this with my fiddle? I am trying to replicate the way it is in my screenshot.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I have put the content in the drop-down menu. Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/17/embedded/result/) I am wondering in which class I have to do styling in order to change the color of the text in the dropdown. I want the color of the text to be black in the drop-down.

Comment: I tried putting `color:black` here in the below class but it didn't work.  

`.dropdown {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
}`

Comment: `a` inherently has the color blue. So either `a { color: black }` or `.dropdown a {color: black}`

Answer (score 1):

Giving really basic idea only, you have to bind the click event on that  tag like this:

```
$('.nav-top-searchbar > form > img').click(function() {
    $('.body-manage-attendees').show();
})
```

also, usually it's being said that using 'ul' & 'li' combination is the best practice for making a dropdown, instead of using divs.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use javascript, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468554/dropdown-menu-without-javascript

you can do on :hover, without using javascript, but if you want to show dropdown when the button is clicked, maybe it's impossible.

Comment: I can use Javascript. Do you think you can provide an example with jsfiddle to make it clear for me?